# find the value of (a^n!)%p

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

i can find the value by doing ((a^n)%p)^(n-1)!)%p but i am looking for a more easier/efficient way of doing it as a^n is pretty big.

PS this is my first question plzz pardon me if i am getting any protocol wrong

Comment: Please learn to use $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so that we can understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Think about Fermat’s Little Theorem: If $p$ is prime and $p\nmid a$ then
$$
a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}
$$
So if $p-1|n!$ then $a^{n!}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: little more elaboration is needed i am not a pure math student

Comment: Time to start learning then! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: i would like to know that fermat works only when p is prime what happens when its not prime was able to solve for primes using fermat's theorm